# Line up CAD model and point cloud in Revit

Tags: autocad, point-clouds, cad, revit

So, I am working with Revit, where I want to match a CAD model (.dwg) and the actual point cloud. So far I was only able to add both of them, but they do have different scaling. Can anything be done in Revit in order to line them up?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to manually change the "Scale" property of the point cloud within Revit

> Scale 
>   Specifies the conversion coefficient from the source units to feet. For example, if the source unit is meters, then the Scale value is 3.2808. If the source unit is feet, then the Scale value is 1.
>
> Modify the scale value if units of the source data have not been correctly determined during import of the point cloud file.

- https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Revit-Model/files/GUID-5CBB12C7-D588-45BC-8245-39BD8E8FCF32-htm.html

For reference: Revit uses Imperial Feet as it's default method of measuring length values.